# Validation of Specific Date using Php or Javascript CONT'D

Tags: php

This is a continuation of: [Validation of Specific Date using Php or Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846439/validation-of-specific-date-using-php-or-javascript)

My code looks like:

```
<?php 

$month = $_POST["mo"];
$day = $_POST["theDay"];
$yr = $_POST["year"];
if (checkdate($month, $day, $yr) !== true)  {
    // ?
}

function checkLeap(el) {
    var year = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    return (new Date(year,1,29).getDate() == 29);
}


if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if page is not submitted; echo form
?>

<h2 style="margin:0; padding:0;">Date Selection</h2>
 <span style="color:gray; font-size:0.8em;">By Joseph Dickinson</span>
<FORM method="POST" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"> 
 <select name="mo">
   <option disabled="disabled">SELECT MONTH</option>
   <option value="1">January</option>
   <option value="2">February</option>
   <option value="3">March</option>
   <option value="4">April</option>
   <option value="5">May</option>
   <option value="6">June</option>
   <option value="7">July</option>
   <option value="8">August</option>
   <option value="9">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">December</option>
 </select>
 <select name="theDay">
   <option disabled="disabled">SELECT DAY</option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
   <option>11</option>
   <option>12</option>
   <option>13</option>
   <option>14</option>
   <option>15</option>
   <option>16</option>
   <option>17</option>
   <option>18</option>
   <option>19</option>
   <option>20</option>
   <option>21</option>
   <option>22</option>
   <option>23</option>
   <option>24</option>
   <option>25</option>
   <option>26</option>
   <option>27</option>
   <option>28</option>
   <option>29</option>
   <option>30</option>
   <option>31</option>
 </select>

 <select name="year" onchange="checkLeap(this)">
   <option disabled="disabled">SELECT YEAR</option>
   <option>2011</option>
   <option>2010</option>
   <option>2009</option>
   <option>2008</option>
   <option>2007</option>
   <option>2006</option>
   <option>2005</option>
   <option>2004</option>
   <option>2003</option>
   <option>2002</option>
   <option>2001</option>
   <option>2000</option>
   <option>1999</option>
   <option>1998</option>
   <option>1997</option>
   <option>1996</option>
   <option>1995</option>
   <option>1994</option>
   <option>1993</option>
   <option>1992</option>
   <option>1991</option>
   <option>1990</option>
   <option>1989</option>
   <option>1988</option>
   <option>1987</option>
   <option>1986</option>
   <option>1985</option>
   <option>1984</option>
   <option>1983</option>
   <option>1982</option>
   <option>1981</option>
   <option>1982</option>
 </select>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
</FORM>
<?
} else { 
echo "You chose: " . " ". $month . " ".$day . ", ". $yr;
}
?>
```

Its giving me an error on LINE 10: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE on line 10

Help please :)

Comment: You seem to be mixing JavaScript with PHP, which can't work. You will need to close the PHP code using `?>` first. It would be better to post follow-up comments in the original question rather than starting a new one

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at line 10, bearing in mind that variables in PHP begin with a `$`.

Comment: function checkLeap(el) { is line 10

Comment: Yes, I know that. This defines a new function in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Line 10 should read

```
function checkLeap($el) {
```